# TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer in if loop python

Tags: python, arrays, sum

I am trying to execute the following lines in python, however, I got an error and searched for several answer, but still can not find how to solve the problem:

attached is the script

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([5,31,41,51,61])
y=np.array([[1,11,21,31,5],[4,14,24,34,5],
        [7,17,27,37,5],[34,44,54,64,5],[37,47,57,67,5]])
for i in range(len(x)-1,2,-2):
    if (np.sum(y==x[i],'all')<.1):
        x=x-(x>y(i))
  # Expected   result is x=[[1,11,21,31,5],[4,14,24,34,5],
                            #[7,17,27,37,5],[34,43,52,61,5]
                             # ,[37,46,55,64,5]]
```

Comment: What is the `'all'` argument to `np.sum()` supposed to be? The second argument to `np.sum()` is supposed to be the axis along which the sum should be performed. If you want to sum all the elements of the array, leave out the argument or use `None`.

Comment: So you get an argument because that argument must be either an integer, a tuple of integers, or `None`. A string is not allowed.

Comment: @Barmar
works perfectly with None